# Save the file and display it in plot

Tags: r

This is my code:

```
    setwd("d://")
     
    jpeg(file="Rplot.jpeg")
     
    plot(1:10)
     
    dev.off()
```

I want to konw how can I Display and save the plot simultaneously in RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
setwd("d://")
jpeg(file="Rplot.jpeg")  
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
plot(1:10)
```

Comment: yes,I want to ask another question,How can I solve this problem with non-repetitive code?

Comment: I use the 'tidyverse', so instead of `jpeg()` and `plot()` I create plots using `ggplot()` then save them with `ggsave()`. A good overview of ggplot can be found [here](http://tutorials.iq.harvard.edu/R/Rgraphics/Rgraphics.html) and a guide to using ggsave can be found [here](https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/how-to-save-a-ggplot/)